# After a system freeze and "hard" restart, laptop monitor no longer works in a dual monitor setup

Tags: 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I'm currently running a Dual Monitor set up (Lenovo Y740 17" with GTX 2080 Max-Q, with a BenQ EX2780Q monitor as the 2nd monitor). My Ubuntu version is 18.04.5.

Was booting up a game when my system became insanely slow/unresponsive. (If I had to guess, I ran out of ram and didn't free enough up before starting the game) After 5 minutes of waiting, I held the power button to shut it off, then went to restart it. However, much to my dismay, when I tried to log in, my laptop display froze, while my secondary display worked as normal. Initially, the monitor just froze on the purple screen with the mouse cursor after login, however now it freezes on the black start up screen after finishing the following line:

`/dev/nume0n1p4: clean, 922740/21626880 files, 56368471/86507520 blocks`

After it shows that, it has the login screen appear on the 2nd monitor.

I have:

- Tried uninstalling and reinstalling Nvidia Drivers in case they were being
  dumb
- Tried adding the `nomodeset` line to grub
- Tried adding `nouveau.modeset=0` to grub
- Using an older kernel and updating that

I'm just about at my wits end, and while the system is usable... I really kind of like having both monitors in a dual monitor set up work, you know?

Any and all advice appreciated, and thank you for your time.

-FullerBot

EDIT 1: It's now back to freezing with the mouse cursor and purple screen immediately after entering the login information. Another interesting thing is that the laptop monitor *will* shut off when I send the computer to sleep/suspend.

---

Answer (score 0):

Followed the bottom solution from this post:
[Update to nvidia-drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 makes my laptop display not accessible but external display is working](https://superuser.com/questions/1369855/update-to-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-makes-my-laptop-display-not-accessible).

For whatever reason, deleting `xorg.conf` did the trick. (So far, anyway)

EDIT: So when I went in to the NVIDIA server thing and enabled G-Sync on my 2nd monitor, it made a new `xorg.conf` file. As a test, I rebooted my machine and the problem returned. For whatever reason, my machine/NVIDIA drivers *do not* like enabling G-Sync on a G-Sync Compatible display. (That, or having the `xorg.conf` file to begin with causes problems. Not sure)